# Is it preferred to use methods on RegExp objects or String objects?

Tags: javascript

There are regex matching methods on both `RegExp` objects and `String` objects in Javascript.

`RegExp` objects have the methods

- exec
- test

`String` objects have the methods

- match
- search

The `exec` and `match` methods are very similar:

```
/word/.exec("words");
//Result: ["word"]
"words".match(/word/);
//Result: ["word"]

/word/.exec("No match");
//Result: null
"No match".match(/word/);
//Result: null

/word/g.exec("word word");
//Result: ["word"]
"word word".match(/word/g);
//Result: ["word", "word"]
```

and the `test` and `search` are also very similar:

```
/word/.test("words");
//Result: true
"words".search(/word/);
//Result: 0
//Which can converted to a boolean:
"word".search(/word/) > -1;
//Result: true

/word/.test("No match");
//Result: false
"No match".search(/word/) > -1;
//Result: false
```

Is there a preference to use the methods on `RegExp` objects or on `String` objects?

Comment: other than personal preference?  In general I find the string methods easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Mostly Personal Preference

This is mostly personal preference, though there is a slight difference in capabilities (see last paragraph for that difference).  Unless you want to start benchmarking performance measurements and turn the question into one of performance, it's mostly personal preference.

I prefer to do:

```
string.match(/word/)
```

because I think that makes the code read like my brain thinks of the operation.  I'm taking the string object and looking for a particular regular expression in it.  It makes sense to me that looking for something in a string is a method on the string object.  This reads to me like:

```
object.action(tool)
```

which is how object oriented code should work in my opinion.

If you have:

```
/word/.match(string)
```

then to me it feels like:

```
tool.action(object)
```

which I find a lot less logical and less object-oriented.  Yes, `/word/` is technically an object too, but it's not the object I'm trying to operate on, I think of it more like a tool or a parameter I'm using with my object.

Obviously both work.  You can decide for yourself which you like.

### One Major Difference

There are a few things that I believe you can only do on a regular expression object.  For example, if you want to match all occurrences of a regular expression, you have to create the regular expression object, pass it the "g" option and then call `re.exec()` multiple times to get each match until exec returns null indicating no more matches.  I don't think you can do that with `string.match()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences between `match` and `exec` when using the global flag `g`. You can't loop through global occourences with `match`, while using `exec` you can:

```
var string="xabx xnnx";
var regexp=new RegExp('x([^x]*)x','g');

// match returns the list of matching parts:
string.match(regexp) // ["xabx", "xnnx"]

// with exec you could build a loop:
var match=regexp.exec(string);
while (match) {
    console.log(match);
    match=regexp.exec(string);
}
// This loops through matches and returns subpatterns too:
// ["xabx", "ab"]
// ["xnnx", "nn"]
```

And `index` doesn't work at all when using `match` with a globalized `RegExp` object:

```
var r=/b/g;
r.exec("0123b56b").index // 4
r.exec("0123b56b").index // 7
"0123b56b".match(r).index // undefined
"0123b56b".match(/b/).index // 4
```